# Did Wonder Woman (2017) receive an official Hindi dub?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman, dubbing

Did *Wonder Woman* (2017) receive an official dub into the Hindi language? [Several](https://www.quora.com/Will-the-Wonder-Woman-movie-be-dubbed-in-Hindi) [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Isn%E2%80%99t-the-Wonder-Woman-movie-releasing-in-Hindi-language) [questions](https://www.quora.com/Will-Wonder-Woman-be-released-in-Hindi-in-India) say that it would not, but I found people pointing to pirated versions of the movie in Hindi. Was an official dub produced, or are all the ones floating around fan dubs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

From [Pursuenews.com](http://pursuenews.com/exclusive-justice-league-release-dubbed-versions-india/):

> An inside source has confirmed that Justice League will be releasing in Tamil, Hindi and Telugu. The news doesn’t come as a surprise as the magnitude for the movie is much higher.
>
> Earlier, DCEU fans in India were disappointed as Wonder Woman and Suicide Squad were only released in the original English version. The incident also led many to question if Warner Bros. would decide to do the same with Justice League as well.

But even Justice League regional language dub version faced issues:

[Justice League: CBFC* delays release of Hindi, Telugu and Tamil versions due to heavy backlog](http://www.firstpost.com/entertainment/justice-league-cbfc-delays-release-of-hindi-telugu-and-tamil-versions-due-to-heavy-backlog-4214667.html)

<sub>*CBFC stands for [Central Board of Film Certification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Board_of_Film_Certification).</sub>